# react-native websocket ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED stopping network requests

Tags: sockets, websocket, react-native, sockjs

Every now and then our react-native app has a problem connecting to our websocket (we're using **sockjs**). When this happens it blocks all network requests and essentially stops our app from functioning.

When it occurs the console doesn't stop logging:

```
GET http://192.168.0.11.xip.io:8080/sock/194/noeli4ep/eventsource 
net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

This is our connect script, which runs when the app starts, it also runs when socket closes (this is so we can re-connect to the socket).

```
connectToServer() {
    if (!this.flagConnect) {
      this.webSocket = new SockJS(`${config.endpoint}sock`);
      this.webSocket.onopen = this.onOpen; // Just sets this.opened to true
      this.webSocket.onmessage = this.onMesssage; // Just reads the msgs
      this.webSocket.onclose = this.onClose; // Re-calls connectToServer()
      this.webSocket.onerror = this.onError; // Console.logs the error
    }
  }
```

We're using React-native 0.41 & using sockJS on the app & backend (nodejs).

Answer (score 0):

I found that removing `xip.io` fixed this issue.

So using `http://<ip>:><port>` was fine.